# "../Main.java:29: error: constructor JLineConsole in class JLineConsole cannot be applied to given types;" when trying to make JAR from a Python file

Tags: java, python, jar, jython

```
../Main.java:29: error: constructor JLineConsole in class JLineConsole cannot be applied to given types;
        return new JLineConsole();
               ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

is the exact error I'm getting.  I'm following the directions found [here](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts), but I'm stuck repeatedly at the portion after one adds their libs to Jython/Lib:

```
$ javac ../Main.java -d .
```

When I try executing this command is when the error mentioned above is thrown.  Here is the relevant Java:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.python.core.Py;
import org.python.core.PyException;
import org.python.core.PyFile;
import org.python.core.PySystemState;
import org.python.util.JLineConsole;
import org.python.util.InteractiveConsole;
import org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter;

public class Main {
    private static InteractiveConsole newInterpreter(boolean interactiveStdin) {
        if (!interactiveStdin) {
            return new InteractiveConsole();
        }

        String interpClass = PySystemState.registry.getProperty(
        "python.console", "");
        if (interpClass.length() > 0) {
            try {
                return (InteractiveConsole)Class.forName(
            interpClass).newInstance();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // fall through
            }
        }
        return new JLineConsole();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException {
        PySystemState.initialize(
            PySystemState.getBaseProperties(), 
            new Properties(), args);

        PySystemState systemState = Py.getSystemState();
        // Decide if stdin is interactive
        boolean interactive = ((PyFile)Py.defaultSystemState.stdin).isatty();
        if (!interactive) {
            systemState.ps1 = systemState.ps2 = Py.EmptyString;
        }

        // Now create an interpreter
        InteractiveConsole interp = newInterpreter(interactive);
        systemState.__setattr__("_jy_interpreter", Py.java2py(interp));
        interp.exec("try:\n import entrypoint\n entrypoint.main()\nexcept SystemExit: pass");
    }
}
```

I'm not particularly well-versed in Java, but from what I do know, I don't see anything wrong with this.

I've tried this a number of times and looked up the StackOverflow questions related to the error message I'm getting, but none of them seem to be applicable.

I also tried just running the Java file itself with the command `$ java ../Main.java`.   This threw a different error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class ...Main.java`
which I've looked up on here, but none of those errors seem to be applicable to my case either; however, one did give me the suggestion of using `java -Xdiag` to get a more useful error message.  I did, and this produced:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...Main.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Which I kind of understand to be the same as the non-verbose error message, and doesn't really give me a clear path forward.  Does anyone here have any ideas?

Comment: 1) `...Main.java` is not a class. 2) Have you *compiled* `Main.java` with `javac` then used `java -cp . Main`?

Comment: thanks for the response @cricket_007.  1 - I think this is intentional on the part of the person who wrote it - not sure, though. 2 - no, I haven't.  When I try and do that, it gives me all sorts of errors, so I'll try and work those out and then update this answer as needed.

Comment: Basically, my point is that the `java` command expects you to run a `class` file, which comes from compiling with `javac`

Comment: Regarding the first error. I'm not seeing a [`JConsole`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/JLineConsole.html#JLineConsole()) constructor that accepts a string

Comment: hm. I think I'll need to bone up on Java a little bit more before tackling this, then.. I don't really know what a class file is or how to make a JConsole constructor.  thanks for trying to help, though!

Comment: I'm reading that link you posted, and it never uses `java ../Main.java` to run the program. It uses `jar -cfe output.jar Main *` after `javac ../Main.java -d .`, but your code is unable to compile because `JConsole` has a problem. However, you should not need to create one because that is included as part of the library that you are trying to use.

Comment: hm. I changed the part that was returning JLineConsole(), and it compiled, but then it started throwing python import errors, chiefly "No module named test" which I fixed by putting the test module in the jython Lib dir, and then it threw `cannot import name main`.  I really appreciate the help thus far, but I think this problem may be a little larger than I had anticipated.